# How to get count of urls present in sitemap.xml file

Tags: cypress, sitemap.xml

Can anyone help me to know how we can take count of urls present in sitemap.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery to count the urls

```js
cy.request('sitemap.xml')
  .its('body')
  .then(xml => {
    const count = Cypress.$(xml).find('url').length;
    cy.log(count)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your url’s have `a` tags, and you have to assert the count you can do like this:

```js
cy.get('a').should('have.length', 10)
```

If you just want to print the length you can like this:

```js
cy.get('a')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    cy.log(len) //prints length
  })
```